# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'OF'.'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Nuevamente yo solicitando su colaboracion tengo un inconveniente el cual he estado analizando sin encontrar el error me genera el siguiente error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'OF'.'

Ya verifique en la base de datos y la columna tiene exactamente ese nombre y en la demas parte del codigo no encuentro el error

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into Arope(REGION,DEPENDENCIA,OPERACION,SIGLAUNIDAD,SECCION,DEPARTAMENTO,MUNICIPIO,OF,SUB,PT,TOTALFD,GR,NOMBRESYAPELLIDOS," +
            "CEDULA,CARGO,UBICACION,MISION,ACTOADMIN,LATITUD,LONGITUD) values (@region,@dependencia,@operacion,@siglaUnidad,@seccion,@departamento,@municipio,@of,@sub,@pt,@totalFd,@gr,@nombresyapellidos,@cedula" +
            "@cargo,@ubicacion,@mision,@actoAdmin,@latitud,@longitud)", conec);
comando.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@dependencia", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@operacion", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@siglaUnidad", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@seccion", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@departamento", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@municipio", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@of", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@sub", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@pt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@totalFd", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@gr", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@nombresyapellidos", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@cedula", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@cargo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@ubicacion", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@mision", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@actoAdmin", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@latitud", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters.Add("@longitud", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comando.Parameters["@region"].Value = arope.Region;
        comando.Parameters["@dependencia"].Value = arope.Dependencia;
        comando.Parameters["@operacion"].Value = arope.Operacion;
        comando.Parameters["@siglaUnidad"].Value = arope.Sigla;
        comando.Parameters["@seccion"].Value = arope.Seccion;
        comando.Parameters["@departamento"].Value = arope.Departamento;
        comando.Parameters["@municipio"].Value = arope.Municipio;
        comando.Parameters["@of"].Value = arope.Oficiales;
        comando.Parameters["@sub"].Value = arope.NivelEje;
        comando.Parameters["@pt"].Value = arope.Patrulleros;
        comando.Parameters["@totalFd"].Value = arope.TotalFd;
        comando.Parameters["@gr"].Value = arope.Grado;
        comando.Parameters["@nombresyapellidos"].Value = arope.ApellidosNombres;
        comando.Parameters["@cedula"].Value = arope.Cedula;
        comando.Parameters["@cargo"].Value = arope.cargo;
        comando.Parameters["@ubicacion"].Value = arope.UbicacionActual;
        comando.Parameters["@mision"].Value = arope.Mision;
        comando.Parameters["@actoAdmin"].Value = arope.ActoAdmi;
        comando.Parameters["@latitud"].Value = arope.Latitud;
        comando.Parameters["@longitud"].Value = arope.Longitud;
        conec.Open();
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conec.Close();
        return i;
```

el error me lo indica en  int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
agradezco su colacoracion pues no veo nada mal en el codigo compila y todo pero al momento de tratar de dar alta a esos datos me salta a ese error

Comment: Te ahorras la mitad de las lineas con `AddWithValue`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que OF es una palabra clave dentro del lenguaje SQL SERVER por lo que debes agregar corchetes para que te lo reconozca. Intenta con esta sentencia:

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into Arope(REGION,DEPENDENCIA,OPERACION,SIGLAUNIDAD,SECCION,DEPARTAMENTO,MUNICIPIO,[OF],SUB,PT,TOTALFD,GR,NOMBRESYAPELLIDOS," +
            "CEDULA,CARGO,UBICACION,MISION,ACTOADMIN,LATITUD,LONGITUD) values (@region,@dependencia,@operacion,@siglaUnidad,@seccion,@departamento,@municipio,@of,@sub,@pt,@totalFd,@gr,@nombresyapellidos,@cedula" +
            "@cargo,@ubicacion,@mision,@actoAdmin,@latitud,@longitud)", conec);
```

Espero resulte útil.

Comment: Si tienes toda la razón, ya con solo eso logre que corriera sin ese error, muchas gracias por su colaboración compañero desconocia eso, ahora como todos en la programación solucionar los nuevos errores que salieron :D

Comment: Genial, para futuras lecturas de este tópico. Se debe evitar el uso de palabras claves y con espacios como nombre de columnas. Saludos